# Multiple child tables

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I would like to know what is the best solution for making a parent table with multiple children?

I have to make multiple children table. One for each profile.

Is there a better idea than having 3 foreign keys in the parent table?

Comment: Can you give more specifics? What kind of profiles are we talking about, and how will their columns be modeled differently? Will one row in the parent table have exactly one profile in one of the three tables, or potentially more than one? Also if this is more than just theoretical and you want any platform-specific code you should specify which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Only one the the childs will be linked to the parent. I'm planning to use a lightweight sql DB like noSQL, maybe MySQL but not Access.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this (assuming I'm understanding you correctly) via having foreign keys in your child tables referring to the parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
        ParentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE ChildOne (
        ChildOneID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        ParentID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Parent(ParentID) )

CREATE TABLE ChildTwo (
        ChildTwoID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        ParentID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Parent(ParentID) )
```

Comment: This way, it's not reversing parent and child? IS the definition of a parent the one who is referenced by the foreign key or the starting table of a query? Now it's SELECT * FROM ChildOne INNER JOIN Parent on...

Answer (score 1):

If you want each row in parent table to have details only in one table, you can slightly modify **Simon Righarts** solution:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    subtype CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT(ParentID,subtype),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_PARENT_SUBTYPE CHECK (subtype IN 'A','B'));


CREATE TABLE ChildOne (
    ChildOneID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subtype CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_ONE FOREIGN KEY (ParentID,subtype) REFERENCES Parent(ParentID,subtype),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_CHIL_DONE_SUBTYPE CHECK (subtype ='A'));

CREATE TABLE ChildTwo (
    ChildOneID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subtype CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TWO FOREIGN KEY (ParentID,subtype) REFERENCES Parent(ParentID,subtype),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_CHILD_TWO_SUBTYPE CHECK (subtype ='B'));
```

This way `ChildOne` will only contain details for `A` master records, and `ChildTwo` for `B` master records.

Comment: What about a parent with a subtype B having a child A?

Comment: The design above won't let `B` parent have `A` child. In some cases it's useful